# distcp from s3 to hadoop - file not found

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, cloudera

I am getting the below error about a file not found.  Well...the file exists.  I am a newbie with distcp.  I am using cloudera FYI.

```
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-development/test/201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hadoop distcp -i 201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz s3://id:key@test-development/test/201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz
13/05/04 14:54:29 INFO tools.DistCp: srcPaths=[201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz]
13/05/04 14:54:29 INFO tools.DistCp: destPath=s3://id:key@test-development/test/201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz
With failures, global counters are inaccurate; consider running with -i
Copy failed: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input source 201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.checkSrcPath(DistCp.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.copy(DistCp.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:881)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:908)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first param is the source so it should be the path to S3 and the path should be s3n:// and not s3:// (native s3) unless you've written the data to S3 using s3:// (block file system)

Comment: You mean if the data is written using "s3://", then you can only retrieve it with "s3://", and the same with "s3n://" ?